# Docusign - How to customize the color of tabs?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using java SDK, embedded signing view.
I want to put a 'Decline' tabs and potentially some customized tabs. I want to customize the button color, now by default, it shows 'gray'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can customize "Approve" or "Decline" button color, instead you can change their `text color` or even `change the text` as well. Instead of "Approve" you can name it as something else like Accept.